# how to make div extend to bottom of screen

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  background-color: #bada55;
  width: 475px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

I have a div I want to extend to bottom of screen. I'm not sure why but this is not working for me:

```
div {
    background-color: #bada55;
    width: 475px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 100%;
} 


html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me? What are you seeing on your end? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: `body { min-height: 100vh; } div { margin-top: auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize margin & padding like  `*{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}`

```css
div {
  background-color: #bada55;
  width: 475px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
     
}
 *{
  margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```